How to mount and run a bootx64.efi file on Hyper-V?
I've built one of the bflat sample applications for direct running on UEFI. Now I have the boot folder and the bootx64.efi file for my application.
What am I doing wrong that this application can't run? Is there a problem with the image file or something else?
Here's the file I tried to run in case you want to check it: https://file.io/b5cg47YHEkXZ
Also, this is the instruction to run this sample app on QEMU: https://github.com/bflattened/bflat/tree/master/samples/Snake#:~:text=To%20run%20this%20with%20QEMU
Update: This is what I do to make the VM:

I open CMD in the source folder containing the efi/boot/...
I open diskpart and run these commands:

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22621.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: MATIN

DISKPART> create vdisk file=F:\disk.vhdx maximum=500

  100 percent completed

DiskPart successfully created the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> select vdisk file=F:\disk.vhdx

DiskPart successfully selected the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> attach vdisk

  100 percent completed

DiskPart successfully attached the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> convert gpt

DiskPart successfully converted the selected disk to GPT format.

DISKPART> create partition efi size=100

DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> format quick fs=fat32 label="System"

  100 percent completed

DiskPart successfully formatted the volume.

DISKPART> assign letter="X"

DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point.

DISKPART> exit


Then, I copy the file to the attached drive X::

C:\Source\bflat\samples\Snake>xcopy efi\boot\BOOTX64.EFI X:\EFI\BOOT\
efi\boot\BOOTX64.EFI
1 File(s) copied


After that, I reopen diskpart and run these commands:

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22621.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: MATIN

DISKPART> select vdisk file=F:\disk.vhdx

DiskPart successfully selected the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> select partition 2

Partition 2 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> remove letter=X

DiskPart successfully removed the drive letter or mount point.

DISKPART> detach vdisk

DiskPart successfully detached the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> exit


Now, according to the given instructions, the virtual disk is ready. So I open Hyper-V Manager and do New -> Virtual Machine
I name it BootTest and set the location to default
Then, I set the Generation to Gen-2 to support UEFI
I assign 2048MB memory and disable Dynamic Memory as it might cause the problem
Then, I set the connection to "Not Connected"
Next, I connect the VHDX file stored in the drive F: to the VM as below:



Now, this is what displayed in the Summary:

Description:

Name:
Generation: Generation 2
Memory:
Network:
Hard Disk:

BootTest

2048 MB
Not Connected
F:\disk.vhdx (VHDX, fixed size)

I also disable Secure Boot, as it might cause problems too:

Now, I open the VM connect to it, and run it, this is the error shown:


Yes, there's a problem which apparently causes the UEFI to try PXE boot and then the DVD, without success. But I can't tell what error.

@John secure boot is disabled as you can see in the 2nd screenshot's side menu

You can’t just slap the files in an ISO image. Please describe what exactly you did, so we can provide improved instructions. // (Also, why not just follow the instructions on the snake example and create a VHDX?)

I want to use Hyper-V, not QEMU @DanielB

VHDX is a Microsoft format. The VHDX instructions are for Hyper-V. The site you link to also mentions this.

The instructions you link to contain nothing about creating an ISO image. To be UEFI-bootable, an ISO image must satisfy certain requirements. Unless it absolutely has to be an ISO image, I recommend sticking to the method that actually is in the instructions: Creating a virtual disk image, then attaching it to the VM as a virtual hard drive.
I’ll quote the relevant instructions from this page here:

If you're on Windows, you can also execute this under Hyper-V.
First create a virtual disk with a FAT32 filesystem:
$ diskpart
create vdisk file=disk.vhdx maximum=500
select vdisk file=disk.vhdx
attach vdisk
convert gpt
create partition efi size=100
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter="X"
exit
$ xcopy efi\boot\BOOTX64.EFI X:\EFI\BOOT\
$ diskpart
select vdisk file=disk.vhdx
select partition 2
remove letter=X
detach vdisk
exit

Then create a Gen2 virtual machine with the hard disk. Make sure to disable secure boot.

I have verified that this works. The result isn’t very pretty, but the game runs and is controllable.
You need to adapt the instructions at certain points, for example the path to disk.vhdx needs to be absolute.

I did everything the instructions say and made the disk.vhdx on E: drive. But still, it can't find an operating system to load. I also tried disabling dynamic memory, network adapter, and integration services.

You did add a virtual disk drive pointing at disk.vhdx, right? Please provide, in your question, a screenshot of the VM configuration dialog.

I just added all I did in detail to the question's body. If you need any other info, please let me know

Looks good. These are the exact steps that work for me. Maybe something went wrong when compiling the sample to BOOTX64.EFI on your system. I got a file that is 7168 bytes in size. If you open the file in a text editor, it starts with “MZx”.

Mine starts with that too. This is my file's MD5 If it helps: ebb586b3fadf2a4d48bec1508b998f61

Because the executable contains a local path, comparing the hash won’t work. I have exported a working VM, you can get it here: https://github.com/fuzzykiller/snake-vm // Only import it if you trust the file.

The VM you provided worked like a charm! But I also was able to make that myself by just rebuilding the code.
